# Rcpp how to add a column (or row) to an xts object?

Tags: r, time-series, rcpp, xts

Given the following starting R code:

```
x <- structure(
  c(10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 11L, 11L, 11L),
  .Dim = c(7L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Bid", "Ask")),
  index = structure(1:7, tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")),
  .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "",
  tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "", class = c("xts", "zoo"))
a <- 0
a[1:nrow(x)]<-0
b = cbind(x,a)
                    Bid Ask ..2
1969-12-31 18:00:01  10  11   0
1969-12-31 18:00:02  10  11   0
1969-12-31 18:00:03  11  12   0
1969-12-31 18:00:04  12  13   0
1969-12-31 18:00:05  10  11   0
1969-12-31 18:00:06  10  11   0
1969-12-31 18:00:07  10  11   0
```

This works perfectly fine in R, but I need to be able to do this in Rcpp and have it be fast, and most importantly keep the XTS object parameters.

There is a `cbind` function in Rcpp which results in the correct output but looses all XTS traits.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericMatrix AddColumn(const Rcpp::NumericMatrix& X)
{
  int vector_size = PriceMatrix.nrow();
  NumericMatrix aa(vector_size,1);
  NumericMatrix res = cbind(X,aa);
  return wrap(res);
}
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10   11    0
[2,]   10   11    0
[3,]   11   12    0
[4,]   12   13    0
[5,]   10   11    0
[6,]   10   11    0
[7,]   10   11    0
```

Same result, but none of what makes it an xts object.

How can I do basic operations like adding columns or rows while keeping the xts object?

Comment: Look at the Rcpp Gallery about how to _create_ an xts from C++, then infer how to _recover_ the attribute before altering the matrix and re-attaching the attribute.

Comment: Thanks, I assume you are referring to this http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/creating-xts-from-c++/ Is this the only way, as it seem inefficient. Also, the xts stores the dimensions and column names of the resulting object. If I copy the attributes from the my X matrix do I need to change those values?